# XLWORKBOOK.CS is not found

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-access, closedxml

With the below code I have loaded Datatable in WPF from ms access DB using c# but not sure how to export the same Datatable to Excel.

```
 try
{
OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection();
connect.ConnectionString = 
@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DataSource=|DataDirectory|\Electricalcircuits.mdb";[enter image description here][1]

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "Select * from REPORT";
cmd.Connection = connect;
connect.Open();
System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
OleDbDataAdapter DA = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
DA.Fill(dt);
}
catch (OleDbException ex)
{
MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

I tried using closedxml library after installing it from Nuget package installer. Getting error " xlworkbook.cs not found" while running the application.
code used for export:

```
string folderPath = "C:\\Excel\\"; 
if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath)) 
{ 
Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath); 
} 
using (ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook wb = new ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook()) 
{ 
wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, "Customers"); wb.SaveAs(folderPath + "Report.xlsx"); 
}
```

Comment: I am not sure but try this (adding reference) :  Solution Explorer > Reference > Right click > Add Reference > COM Tab > Search for Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library (or lower depending on your excel.)  REF : https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1042021/Type-or-namespace-XLWorkbook-Could-not-be-found

Comment: I tried it already, still the same error